# How can I get a Windows 11 Context Menu item to work with my PyQt6 application

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyqt, contextmenu

I have a python script that I would like to run from the Windows 11/10 Right Click Context Menu in my documents folder
`"C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\PythonScripts\\main.py"`

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('My PyQt6 Application')
window.resize(400, 300)
window.move(100, 100)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

I created a python script that adds an item to the Right Click Context Menu in Windows 11 via registry.

But, The problem I am having is that when I try to click on "My Python Script" in the context menu, a pyqt6 window should pop up.

I tried running the exact command in terminal window
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:\Users\me\Documents\PythonScripts\main.py "%V"`which works with no issues.

```
import winreg
menu_name = "My Python Script"
icon_path = "%SystemRoot%\\system32\\imageres.dll,3"

python = "C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe"

command = f"{python} C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\PythonScripts\\main.py \"%V\""


key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                     r"Directory\Background\shell",
                     0, winreg.KEY_WRITE)

menu_key = winreg.CreateKey(key, menu_name)


winreg.SetValueEx(menu_key, "Icon", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, icon_path)
winreg.SetValueEx(menu_key, "command", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, command)


winreg.CloseKey(menu_key)
winreg.CloseKey(key)
```

Comment: That `python` string seems invalid, as it doesn't use escape characters.

Comment: @musicamante fixed the typo.

Comment: I've not been using Windows in years, but shouldn't the argument be `\"%1\"`?. Also, have you checked the actual registry editor key to see if the command line is correct? The key name still has invalid escape usage.

Answer (score 0):

I found where the issue resided. I was adding the command key incorrectly. I needed to use `command_key = winreg.CreateKey(menu_key, "command")` for the command. Then add the value `winreg.SetValueEx(command_key, "", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, command)`.

```
import winreg

# Name that will appear in the context menu
menu_name = "My Python Script"

# Path to the icon file
icon_path = "%SystemRoot%\\system32\\imageres.dll,3"

python = "C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe"

# Path to the Python script and any command-line arguments
command = f"{python} C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\PythonScripts\\main.py \"%V\""

# Open the registry key
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                 r"Directory\Background\shell",
                 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE)

# Create a new key for our menu item
menu_key = winreg.CreateKey(key, menu_name)
command_key = winreg.CreateKey(menu_key, "command")

# Set the menu item's icon
winreg.SetValueEx(menu_key, "Icon", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, icon_path)

# Create a new key for our menu item
winreg.SetValueEx(command_key, "", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, command)

# Close the keys
winreg.CloseKey(menu_key)
winreg.CloseKey(command_key)
winreg.CloseKey(key)
```